# What's the difference between Hadoop webhdfs and Azure webhdfs

Tags: hdfs, hadoop2, azure-data-lake, webhdfs

Hadoop webhdfs: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.8.0/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Azure webhdfs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-lake-store/data-lake-store-overview

Answer (score 1):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datalakestore/webhdfs-filesystem-apis

Please refer to the above link for full details, but broadly Azure Data Lake Store currently supports WebHDFS version 2.7.2.

Thanks.